# How to limit process thread using POSIX PTHREAD in C?

Tags: c, pthreads, primes

I have a code that count the total of prime number from 1 to 10.000.000 using C. I want to make the process is limited to only using 4 threads. I have read that this can be achieve using pthread library, but I am still confuse how to do that.

this is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {
    int i,n,flag,c;
    int l,r;
    
    l = 1;
    r = 10000000;
    
    c = 0; 
    for(n=l; n<=r; ++n){
        
        // 1 is not prime
        if(n==1)
            continue;
        
        flag = 0;
        for(i = 2; i<=sqrt(n); ++i){
            
            if(n%i==0){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(flag==0)
            ++c;
            
    }
    
    printf("Total prime number from %d to %d is: %d\n", l, r, c);
    
}
```

I want to know how to run that code by limiting it with 4 thread.

Comment: your process doesn't use threads (so it has 1 thread). Why do you need to limit it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  You say you want to *limit* the program to using four threads, but it is already single threaded.  It will use only one.

Comment: so in C if the number of thread is not specified it will only use 1 thread?

Comment: yes. Also, when you don't tell it to delete your hard drive, it will not delete your hard drive: C is a very low-level language. It never does anything you don't explicitly tell it to. Plus, even the coolest mighty auto-vectorizing language would have a hard to impossible time parallelizing your code: the way you wrote it is inherently a sequential algorithm.

Comment: It's not merely a matter of specifying the number of threads, but starting each thread with the work that thread is to perform, as well as synchronizing any data shared among threads to avoid race conditions. Concurrency is not simple.

Comment: Some general-purpose programming language runtimes feature additional threads that perform auxiliary tasks, and some application platforms provide easy ways to run multiple instances of a program, but I don't know any general-purpose programming language that automatically parallelizes individual program instances that are not explicitly coded to use multiple threads.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've seen a couple of academic papers go by talking about extending autovectorization of loops to, basically, auto-OpenMP-ifying the same loops, but I don't think any of that has hit production compilers yet.

Comment: "*so in C if the number of thread is not specified it will only use 1 thread?*" If by "thread" you mean pthreads threads, and by "C" you mean pthreads, then yes. Your process starts out with a single pthreads thread and your code doesn't create any more. (Your implementation is free to use other kinds of threads internally that you don't have to think or worry about however it wants, but probably doesn't.)

Answer (score 2):

As many people told you in the comments, your program is only using 1 thread which is executing your main.

If you would like to divide the job of calculating the prime numbers, what you should do is the following;

1. Declare a mutex with `pthread_mutex_t` mtx and initialize it.
   (used to access a shared variable in order to prevent race conditions)
2. Declare an array of `pthread_t` threads[3]
3. Assign the job of calculating the prime numbers in a set range
4. Wait for all the threads to finish
5. Print the count

The program you are looking for would be like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct tps //struct to pass parameters to thread 
{
int begin;
int end;
};

typedef struct tps topass;

pthread_mutex_t mtx=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //initialization mutex
int count=0;

void *job(void*); //prototype of function

int main()
{
  int thworkers=4,prec=1,next=0,currency=0,number=0,i=0;
  topass prms[4];
  pthread_t *Pth;
  scanf("%d",&number);

  currency=number/thworkers;
  next=currency;

  Pth=(pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*thworkers);

  for( i=0; i<thworkers; i++)
  {
     prms[i].begin=prec;
     prms[i].end=next;

     prec=next;
     next+=currency;
  }

  for(i=0;i<thworkers;i++)
  {

     pthread_create(&(Pth[i]),NULL,job,&prms[i]); //creating threads
  }

  for(i=0;i<thworkers;i++)
  {
    pthread_join(Pth[i],NULL); // waiting threads to finish 
  }

  free(Pth);

  printf("Count:%d",count);    //printing result
}

void *job(void *param)
{
    topass *rvd=(topass *)param;
    int n=rvd->begin,r=rvd->end,flag,i;
    for(n=n; n<=r; n++)
    {
       
        // 1 is not prime
        if(n==1)
            continue;
       
        flag = 0;

        for(i = 2; i<=sqrt(n); ++i)
        {
           
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
       
        if(flag==0)
        {
          pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
          count++;
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        }
           
           
     }

}

/*

())())
((-.-)
(()(()
(())(())

*/
```